# Controlar cuando cierro un JFrame

Tags: java, jframe

He creado el siguiente método para controlar cuando se le da a la X a un JFrame (funciona si está escrito en el propio JFrame):

```
    // Con el siguiente método voy a controlar si le doy a la X, por si le dió por error. 
public void cerrar() {
    try {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
                confirmarSalida();
            }
        }); 
        this.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
//Método para confirmar la salida de la aplicación a través de JOptionPane (se pasa al metodo anterior)
public void confirmarSalida(){
    int valor = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "¿Estas seguro de cerrar la aplicación?","Advertencia",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if (valor==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Gracias por su visita.","Gracias",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Mi problema es al intentar pasarlo a una clase para poder reutilizar el código. Incrédulo de mi que pensaba que copiando lo que hice en el el JFrame en una clase iba a funcionar correctamente.

Las líneas que me dan error son las que contienen un this (entiendo que al ser estático no va a funcionar this), y no se cómo crearlo correctamente.

Edición: He intentado usar el nombre de la clase pero no me saltan multiples errores en el cliente:

```
   // Con el siguiente método voy a controlar si le doy a la X, por si le dió por error. 
public static void cerrarndo() {
    try {
        TrabajarFicherosyMas.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
                confirmarSalida();
            }
        }); 
        TrabajarFicherosyMas.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
//Método para confirmar la salida de la aplicación a través de JOptionPane (se pasa al metodo anterior)
public static void confirmarSalida(){
    int valor = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "¿Estas seguro de cerrar la aplicación?","Advertencia",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if (valor==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Gracias por su visita.","Gracias",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente, con los métodos y atributos de instancia controlas el estado de esa instancia (¿está esta instancia visible o no?), así que necesitan la instancia cuyo estado controlan.

Un método **static** no está asociado a ninguna instancia de la clase. Así que no puede usar los métodos y atributos de una instancia (los "no static"), porque no tiene. Lo que si puede usar es obtener una referencia a una instancia y usar sus métodos de instancia.

```
public static void cerrando() {
   try {
      TrabajarFicherosyMas.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE); // ¿A qué JFrame le estás invocando este método? A ninguno.
      addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
          public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
          confirmarSalida();
      }
      }); 
      TrabajarFicherosyMas.setVisible(true); // ¿Qué JFrame estás haciendo visible?
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Tienes que pasarle la instancia que manipulas:

```
public static void cerrando(TrabajarFicherosYMas frame) {
   try {
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
      addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
          public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
          confirmarSalida();
      }
      }); 
      frame.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```